# Node JS: How do I request multiple source codes from different websites?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, npm-request

I get an issue where If I try to use request more than once, it doesn't work. I can give an example:

```
request('https://www.google.com', function (error, response, vBody1) {
    request('https://www.purple.com', function (error, response, vBody2) {
        request('https://www.stackoverflow.com', function (error, response, vBody3) {
            console.log(vBody3);
        });
        console.log(vBody2);
    });
    console.log(vBody1);
});
```

It reads and outputs the body of the first site, but not the next two.
Here is another example:

```
vSites = ['https://www.google.com','https://www.purple.com','https://www.stackoverflow.com'];
for (i = 0; i < vSites.length; i++){
    request(vSites[i], function (error, response, vBody[i]) {
        console.log(vBody[i]);
    });
}
```

This one looks cleaner and I would like this version, but it doesn't work at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the correct solution from [Michael's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43289288/7803502), please be aware the for-loop sends the requests in parallel. Data and error handling could be challenging if you want to do more than `console.log`.

To better handle the requests, I would suggest using an asynchronous control library such as [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) or [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html). In comparison, [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) is easier to understand while [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) provides better code readability.

**Below is an example [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) implementation:**

```
var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');

var vSites = ['https://www.google.com', 'http://www.purple.com','https://www.stackoverflow.com'];
async.map(
  vSites,
  // `async` will call this function for each `vSite`
  function(vSite, next) {
    // Reuse the code inside your for-loop, but call `next` to pass the error and result to the final callback
    request(vSite, function(err, response, vBody) {
      next(err, vBody);
    });
  },
  // The final callback will be executed when all requests are completed or either of them fails
  function(err, results) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(results);
  }
);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

In your loop version you don't need the index on the vBody variable.

```
 var request = require('request');
 vSites = ['https://www.google.com','https://www.purple.com','https://www.stackoverflow.com'];
for (i = 0; i < vSites.length; i++){
       request(vSites[i], function (error, response, vBody) {
        console.log(vBody);
    });
   }
```

This code works fine for me on node v4.3.2